# selected index value in C# with combobox with database

Tags: c#

I am new in c# and I have a question.
 I want to select a value from a combobox and it should show in a label it's age.

What I do is this:

```
 public void FillCombo()
        {
           SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from customers",con);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adap.Fill(dt);
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";

        }

  private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();

           SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select * from customers where name=@name ", con);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",comboBox1.SelectedItem));

           int i= cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (i > 0)
            {
               SqlDataReader sqlrdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            while (sqlrdr.Read())
            {
                String age= sqlrdr["age"].ToString();
                label1.Text = age;
            }

            }

 else{
MessageBox.Show("no value");
}

con.Close();
    }
```

It shows no value message , even if i have values in database. What can I do?

Comment: `SelectedIndex` is not what you want to use as the `@id`. That is the index of the selection, not the `ValueMember`. Look up how to use `SelectedValue` or `SelectedItem`.

Comment: It looks like you really shouldn't be using `ExecuteNonQuery` at all here.  Not sure why you did that, but if you have to read from the DB (which you shouldn't have to, see Steve's answer below) then just use `ExecuteReader`.  Currently `i` will *always* equal zero because all you're doing is selecting data, not modifying it.

Comment: `cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",comboBox1.Text));`

Comment: @Crowcoder I edited but this is what I get       System.ArgumentException: 'No mapping exists from object type System.Data.DataRowView to a known managed provider native type

Comment: I suggested you look up how to use `SelectedItem` because you can't use it like that. It is an object, you have to reference the corresponding property. Anyway, keep that in mind for when you need it, but this time just look at @Steve 's answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you set the DataSource to a DataTable then every item in the combobox is a [DataRowView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowview?view=netframework-4.7.2). So you already have the info about the age of the current customer in the combobox. No need to make another call to the database.

You just need to use the SelectedItem property to retrieve the info about the *age* field or any other field present in the DataSource

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView rv = l.SelectedItem as DataRowView;

    // For safety, always check for null. 
    // It is possible that SelectedIndexChanged 
    // will be called even when there is no selection in the combobox
    if(rv != null)
    {
        label1.Text = rv["age"].ToString();
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this to obtain index,value and selected name:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
        int selectedIndex = cmb.SelectedIndex;
        int selectedValue = (int)cmb.SelectedValue;
        ComboboxItem selectedName = (ComboboxItem)cmb.SelectedItem;
    }
```